# Python - Multiprocessing Process module - function variable not defined?

Tags: python, function, process, python-multiprocessing, nameerror

I was trying to test some multiprocessing code. below code works fine:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def print_func(continent='Asia'):
    print('The name of continent is : ', continent)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    names = ['America', 'Europe', 'Africa']
    procs = []
    proc = Process(target=print_func)  # instantiating without any argument
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

    # instantiating process with arguments
    for name in names:
        # print(name)
        proc = Process(target=print_func, args=(name,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    # complete the processes
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

However, if I add a new variable within `if __name__ == "__main__":`, and use that variable in `target`, then the `target` function can't recognize the variable.

```
def print_func(continent='Asia'):
    print('The name of continent is : ', continent, ' ', t)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # confirms that the code is under main function
    names = ['America', 'Europe', 'Africa']
    t = 'continent'
    procs = []
    proc = Process(target=print_func)  # instantiating without any argument
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

    # instantiating process with arguments
    for name in names:
        # print(name)
        proc = Process(target=print_func, args=(name,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    # complete the processes
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

It will have error: `NameError: name t is not defined.` This error looks weird to me and it is not reasonable since in a simple code below won't have this issue:

```
import pandas as pd

def my_func(c):
  f['b'] = c
  print(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
    my_func(2)
```

So what's causing the NameError?

Comment: Read (ALL) [multiprocessing-pool-process-global-scope-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353608/pythons-multiprocessing-pool-process-global-scope-problem)

Comment: @stovfl Now I know it is not recommend to share data across processes. But still, is there a way to let multiple process share the same pd.DataFrame at the same time? It seems sharing values/strings/list/dict are possible but not sure if DataFrame is also shareable.

Comment: @stovfl using Namespace() from Manager() seems to work...

Comment: ***"using `Namespace()` from `Manager()` seems to work"***: Feel free to post a community wiki answer, checkbox lower right, to show your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question here. Manager() could be the solution. In the code below, in addition to get access to the string `t`, I also show how we could get access to other python objects such as pandas DataFrame.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def print_func(ns, continent='Asia'):
    p_pd = ns.df
    p_pd.iloc[0] = continent
    print('The name of continent is : ', continent, ' ', ns.t)
    print(p_pd.iloc[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":  # confirms that the code is under main function
    mgr = Manager()
    ns = mgr.Namespace()
    names = ['America', 'Europe', 'Africa']
    ns.t = 'continent'
    ns.df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((2,5)))
    procs = []

    # instantiating process with arguments
    for name in names:
        # print(name)
        proc = Process(target=print_func, args=(ns, name))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    # complete the processes
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```